# Trying to use 'expo start' but getting JSON Error: Unexpected token in JSON

Tags: node.js, reactjs, json, react-native

I've been following the tutorial [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup) to get started with learning React Native. However, I can't seem to get my project to start. I am able to use the `expo init` command to create a project, but when I `cd` to the *AwesomeProject* folder and try to run the `npm start` project, my terminal throws the following error (the below image, specifically the bottom part), and thus I cant open the localhost link.
[image]

Before, when I tried to run `expo start` I would get npm errors, which couldn't seem to be resolved with clearing cache and any other solution. So I completely uninstalled and the reinstalled node.js as well as Expo CLI. Now, the npm error is gone but I have been getting this JSON error that I cannot seem to figure out the cause of.

For reference, this is my `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "awesomeproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

node -v: `v16.15.0`
npm -v: `8.5.4`

Comment: Please show your `package.json`.

Comment: @DavidScholz Alright, I just added the code for package.json, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like outside of `AwesomeProject` directory, there is a `package.json`, which that `package.json` has an extra character against `json` structure and is malformed.

Take a look at the outer `package.json`, if there is any character so remove it and then start your app (The character may be a Unicode character and you may not be able to detect it at first glance, so try to use any tools if needed).

Answer (score 0):

The JSON error shown by metro is inside C:\Code\package.json, however the package.json you posted is in AwesomeProject. You need to run these commands:

1. `delete package.json in C:\Code\package.json`
2. `cd AwesomeProject`
3. `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have run `npm init` outside of the directory of your project which has created a `package.json` file which is causing the error.
Try removing the outer `package.json`, clear the project's cache. And run the project.

I'd also advise installing yarn and using `yarn` against `npm` while installing modules.

Answer (score -1):

This can happen if there is a [nospace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space#:~:text=The%20zero%2Dwidth%20space%20(%E2%80%8B,but%20after%20which%20there%20may) character in your package.json file, which might happen if you didn't copy and paste your package.json properly.

I would advise you to regenerate your package.json file or rewrite the lines which have the issues (in your case, the 1st line).